# Python logging custom formatter in json config does not work

Tags: python

In my python json config file, I have the following formatter where I have kept some custom log fields like applicationName and applicationState

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": true,

    "formatters": {
        "custom": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(applicationName)s,%(applicationState)s] %(message)s"
        }

    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "custom"
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console"]
    },

    "loggers": {
        "myCustomLogger": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

I would then like to have these extras provided by the log statements like this

```
 logger.info("this is my log message", extra={'applicationName': 'myapp', 'applicationStatue': 'Stable'})
```

I get a key error on applicationName and applicationState when I keep these in the json config and load it like this in my python code

```
with open(path, 'rt') as f:
 config = json.load(f)
 logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Error that I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: u'applicationName'
Logged from file _internal.py, line 87
```

However, when I create this formatter in the python code itself like the following, it works fine and I am also able to pass applicationName and applicationState in log extra as explained before

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(applicationName)s,%(applicationState)s] %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Does anyone know how to get this working in json config?

EDIT:

Extra info
I get the logger to log stuff like this:

logging.getLogger("myapp")

Comment: Is that the entire contents of your json file?

Comment: of course not. i didn't paste the whole thing as I thought it would be redundant. Do you want to me send the full contents of the json config file?

Comment: It might help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sure. I just added the entire contents of the json file.

Comment: That file is missing a `}` at the end.  Is that a cut-and-paste error, or is that the real contents?

Comment: it's there but I accidentally left it outside of the formatting area. you can see one extra } outside of the grey code section

Comment: Edited. Should be okay now.

Comment: You've misspelled "applicationState" in your sample code: `'applicationStatue': 'Stable'`.  Once I fixed that, it works for me.

Comment: I fixed that. However, it doesn't even go that far. If fails on applicationName which is not a key defined within python logging like asctime, levelname etc

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the posted code, so I'm not sure what else to do.  Maybe you have a logging statement somewhere that does not pass the `extra` parameter, or passes one with incorrect names?  Although that wouldn't explain why hardcoding the formatter works...

Comment: so if you see my json config file again, there is a logger named myCustomLogger defined. do i need to do logging.getLoggers("myCustomLogger") to get and handle of this logger ?

Comment: actually it was failing on flask default logger 'werkzeug' which would take the custom formatter that I had written for my custom logger. It would try to match my custom formatter string for 'werkzeug' with record.__dict__ and fail. Not sure why it does that. To solve this, since I really don't need the default flask logger for anything, I disabled it by doing a logger.propagate=False and it works fine now. Looks like a dirty fix to me but works fine. If anyone has a better solution then, do let me know